# pyinstaller adding nested modules in hidden imports is not working

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pyinstaller

I am using pyinstaller to convert a ".py" script to exe file. The script takes some CLI parameters and runs scikit-learn and keras models on it and returns the predictions. The '.py' is working fine when being executed like "python3 predict.py".
But, when I use:

```
pyinstaller --onefile predict.py
```

It is giving this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.neighbors._typedefs'
```

But when I do pip3 list, I can clearly see scikit-learn installed there.
After searching on stack overflow I have understood that pyinstaller has trouble while getting second-level dependencies and that can be solved by adding the library in hidden imports. i have done that like this:

```
a = Analysis(['predict.py'],
             pathex=['/Users/mac/Desktop/Fiverr/Clothes_Classification/Scripts'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=['sklearn.neighbors._typedefs'],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
```

but the same error is still there. The model from keras is giving output just fine but all models of sklearn are failing. Also, I am using pickle to load sklearn's models and load_model from keras to load keras models.

I am executing it like this:

```
./predict "/Users/mac/Desktop/Fiverr/Clothes_Classification/Dataset/Images/5336-0010.jpg" "/Users/mac/Desktop/Fiverr/Clothes_Classification/Scripts/Models/"
```

where 2 CLI are given that are used by sys.argv in the program. There is no issue with them I think.

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The .spec file should be modified to hidden-import `typdefs` (notice the missing underscore)
`hiddenimports=['sklearn.neighbors.typedefs'],`

and not
`hiddenimports=['sklearn.neighbors._typedefs'],`
as the error might suggest